# Python Input function not working in IDE 2.7

Tags: python

I have a basic query... The below mentioned program is not running in IDE Python 2.7 Version.
Also please help me to understand what is myName here. Is it a kind of variable? Once i enter the input value its not moving to next statement How are you. Can anyone help me to come out of this basic stuff?

```
print('Hello world!')
print('What is your name?')
myName = input()
print('How are you, ' + myName)
```

Comment: Don't tag both `python-3.x` and `python-2.7`. Tag the version you're **using**. This especially matters for questions involving `input()`.

Comment: In Python 2, you should be using [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), not [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

Answer (score 0):

For inputs in **Python 2.7** use this:

```
myName = raw_input("Enter code here: ")
```

In **Python 3.0** use this:

```
myName = input("Enter code here: ")
```

'myName' is a variable that will hold what the user enters as a string. If you type in "Steve" it will hold that inside 'myName', so when you do something like this:

```
print("My name is, " + myName)
```

It will print out the following:

```
My name is, Steve
```

Comment: 'myName' is a variable that will hold what the user enters. When the 'Enter code here:' is displayed on screen, type in your code/name and press enter. This will send your input to the program, and 'myName' will store that input as a string. Then you can print 'myName' either like this:


`print('How are you, ' + myName)`

or like this:

`print(myName)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic methods to read input from the console in python2.x.

The first one is `input` and the second one is `raw_input` (by the way there are other ways to read from console, not to mention those.)

For `input` you have to enter pure python code that can be evaluated by the interpreter, and for `raw_input` your input will be stored as string that you can later parse for your need.

So to demonstrate:

```
myName = input('Enter code here: ')
Enter code here: abc
```

This one will raise a `NameError: name 'abc' is not defined`.

While:

```
myName = raw_input('Enter text here: ')
Enter text here: abc
```

Will pass, and store the string `abc` in the variable called `myName`.

Although you can get the same result with `input` if you type your input between quotes:

```
myName = input('Enter code here: ')
Enter code here: 'abc'
```

As a conclusion you should never use `input` to get text from the console, as it will be interpreted as pure python code and can lead to dangerous and undesired results, instead always use `raw_input`.

Hope it helps!

Note: in python3 `raw_input`'s equivalent is `input` and the old `input` is gone.